# Использование func_get_args, func_get_arg в качестве аргумента

Tags: c, php

Лыжи не едут.

```
function some_function(){
  $param1 = 'foobar';
  myfunction($param1,func_get_args());
}
```

Выводит ошибку: невозможно использовать func_get_args() в качестве параметра. 
ВОПРОС1: почему?

```
function some_function(){
  $param1 = 'foobar';
  myfunction(func_get_args(),$param1);
}
```

Нормально хавается, чудесно передает массив в качестве аргумента.
ВОПРОС2: Почему?!

[bugs.php, Баг №27887](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27887) - читал. Отсюда нашел мегахак с первым аргументом, коим пользуюсь. Но там написано, что вообще низя использовать, и что как раз мегахак и является истинным багом. См. вопрос 1 или 2.

[php manual func-get-arg() Комментарий за 07-Dec-2004 02:56](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php#47974)
Вопрос3: Да что ж такое?!

Вопрос4: как по-уму передать все аргументы функции без переменной-посредника(если возможно)? Либо просто минимальным количеством кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because this function depends on the current scope to determine parameter details, it cannot be used as a function parameter in versions prior to 5.3.0. If this value must be passed, the results should be assigned to a variable, and that variable should be passed.
>
> 5.3.0  This function can now be used in parameter lists.

До PHP 5.3 никак, вестимо.

**UPD.**

> Нормально хавается, чудесно передает массив в качестве аргумента.
>
> ВОПРОС2: Почему?!

[`ZEND_FUNCTION(func_num_args)`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.2/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L168)

```
/* {{{ proto int func_num_args(void)
   Get the number of arguments that were passed to the function */
ZEND_FUNCTION(func_num_args)
{
    void **p;
    int arg_count;

    p = EG(argument_stack).top_element-1-1;
    arg_count = (int)(zend_uintptr_t) *p;       /* this is the amount of arguments passed to func_num_args(); */
    p -= 1+arg_count;
    if (*p) {
        zend_error(E_ERROR, "func_num_args(): Can't be used as a function parameter");
    }
    --p;
    if (p>=EG(argument_stack).elements) {
        RETURN_LONG((long)(zend_uintptr_t) *p);
    } else {
        zend_error(E_WARNING, "func_num_args():  Called from the global scope - no function context");
        RETURN_LONG(-1);
    }
}
/* }}} */
```

Видимо, что в момент вызова функции `func_num_args()` в качестве первого параметра, стек параметров для вызываемой функции еще пуст, соответственно и проверка на наличие параметров в стеке (`if (*p) {`) так же не пройдет, но и не принесет никаких последствий, поскольку параметров в стеке на данный момент действительно 0. Тоже самое относится и к остальным функциям `func_*arg*`

В этом, видимо, и заключается сей полезный баг. Если я не прав, то, возможно, более знающие C'шники смогут прокомментировать эту функцию.

Comment: Это ответ на вопрос 4 и 1. Возможно, еще и на 3.

Comment: @knes, обновил. Устроит вас такой ответ? :)

Comment: Да, вполне